# Barron Webster javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to recreate this video https://www.superhi.com/video/barron-webster but with text and cant seem to get it quite right https://text-9.superhi.com/ the design text is over lapping my name and its showing backwards instead of pushing each other side to side like in the original video.

```js
var originwidth = $('h1').width()
var originheight = $('h1').height()

$(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
  var scaleX = event.pageX / originwidth
  var scaleY = event.pageY / originheight

  $('h1').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY + ')')
})

var originwidth = $('h2').width()
var originheight = $('h2').height()

$(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
  var scaleX = event.pageX / originwidth
  var scaleY = event.pageY / originheight

  $('h2').css('transform', 'scale(' + -scaleX + ',' + scaleY + ')')
})
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

img,
iframe {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  max-width: 100%;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    
    background-color: #ffdc00;
    color: #333333;

}

h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 700;
  
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
    
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 700;
  
  position: fixed;
 top:0;
 right: 0;
    
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>LSNR.B</h1>

<h2>
  DESIGN
</h2>
```

Comment: the `-` in front of `scaleX` in your h2 function is flipping the `DESIGN` text

Comment: [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/6195vcaw/1/) is closer but I don't know why the word "design" doesn't scale out to the left from the fixed right position.  Since you are not working with an image, you would need some more js to scale the words to 50% of the page on page load.

Comment: I've added some js to get the words to be 50% of the page but the design text starts in the place where it was before it scales to 50% so it goes off the page. [new jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/6195vcaw/3/).  Not sure how to keep that word contained to the window.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from [adelriosantiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1996066/adelriosantiago) over at [this post I created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799798/transform-scalex-and-maintain-fixed-right-position).  He figured out that I was missing the proper `transform-origin` property on the `h2` in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/6195vcaw/3).  Setting it to `transform-origin: top right;` makes it all work as in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/6195vcaw/6).

Then he went a step further and really simplified the jquery code as so:

```js
function fixTexts(event) {
  if (!event) {
    // Initial settings when the page is loaded first time
    event = {}
    event.pageX = $(window).width()/2
    event.pageY = $(window).height()/2
  }
  
  // Height is the same for both
  var originheight = $('h2').height()
  
  // For H1
  var originwidth = $('h1').width()
  var scaleX = event.pageX / originwidth
  var scaleY = event.pageY / originheight
  $('h1').css('transform', `scale(${ scaleX }, ${ scaleY })`)
  
  // For H2
  var originwidth = $('h2').width()
  var scaleX = ($(window).width() - event.pageX) / originwidth
  var scaleY = event.pageY / originheight
  $('h2').css('transform', `scale(${ scaleX }, ${ scaleY })`);
}

$(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
  fixTexts(event)
})

fixTexts() // Run first time calculation
```

```css
h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

hgroup {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #ffdc00;
  color: #333333;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: top right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>LSNR.B</h1>
<h2>DESIGN</h2>
```