# Transform scaleX and maintain fixed right position

Tags: html, jquery, css, transform, scale

Using jquery to scale some text with `mousemove` but can't figure out how to make the word on the right (h2) scale out to the left from the right side of the word from the fixed right position.  Instead it always scales from the left edge of the word.

I want the 2 words combined to fill the width of the window at all times and as the cursor moves left, the left word (h1) shrinks and the right word (h2) grows and vice versa.

There is also a problem that I am using some script to scale each word to 50% of the window width on document.ready, but again the right word (h2) scales from its original position based on the css font size and so scales off the page.

Using `text-align: right` has no effect.  How can I keep the right word contained in the window and scale out to the left? [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/6195vcaw/4/)

```js
var originwidth = $('h1').width()
var originheight = $('h1').height()
var origh1scalex = $(window).width()/2 / $('h1').width()
var origh2scalex = $(window).width()/2 / $('h2').width()

$(function() {    
  $('h1').css('transform', 'scaleX(' + origh1scalex + ')'); 
  $('h2').css('transform', 'scaleX(' + origh1scalex + ')');
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
  var scaleX = event.pageX / originwidth
  var scaleY = event.pageY / originheight

  $('h1').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY + ')')
})

var originwidth = $('h2').width()
var originheight = $('h2').height()

$(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
  var scaleX = ($(window).width() - event.pageX) / originwidth
  var scaleY = event.pageY / originheight

  $('h2').css('transform', 'scale(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY + ')')
})
```

```css
h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

hgroup {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #ffdc00;
  color: #333333;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>LSNR.B</h1>
<h2>DESIGN</h2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made several improvements and here is the result: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/RwryoLj?editors=1010

**The issue was a missing `transform-origin: top right;` on the CSS of H2. This sets the origin point where all translations, scale and rotations will be made.**

Also `originwidth` was needed to be calculated inside the `mousemove` event because it changes every time the transform is calculated.

A few other improvements made are:

- Only one `mousemove` event is now used.
- [String template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like `scale(${ scaleX }, ${ scaleY })` are used so that it is easier to discern how the string is built.

This further version allows setting a size when the page is loaded first time and no `mousemove` event has happened yet: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/vYLjybR?editors=0111

Comment: That is excellent for the `mousemove` effect but I do need the initial scale to be 50% of the window for each word. (as if the page loads with the cursor directly in the center of the page).  That was the reason for that code at the top

Comment: Ahh now I get the point of that top code. I have extracted the code into a function and then when there is an event from `mousemove` it will use the data from the mouse, otherwise it will set a 50% size. Here is the sample: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/vYLjybR?editors=0111. You can set the initial settings at the top of the function.

Comment: Also, I found that I missed the real reason why the original code was not working. It was mostly just a missing `transform-origin: top right;` in the CSS. You may want to try that in the original snippet.

Comment: Aha!  So that is why it wouldn't scale out to the left.  This code is awesome.  So much simpler than what I was doing.  Thank you.  Perhaps throw the code into a SO snippet for future users.  The codepen link may not last forever.

Comment: Yep, made that small change in the original snippet and it works perfect.  I still like your code better!